# Convert cypher query to c#

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I have two tables:

```
 User
   Name
   Surname

 Phone
   number
   type_of_number



var myList = ((IRawGraphClient) client).ExecuteGetCypherResults<**i_need_class_to_save_it**>(
                    new CypherQuery("match (a:User)-[r]->(b:Phone) return a,collect(b)", null, CypherResultMode.Set))
                .Select(un => un.Data);
```

How create correct collection to save data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't read https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher or https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher-examples. You really should start there. It helps to read the manual. I don't just write it for fun.

For your specific scenario, let's start with your Cypher query:

```
MATCH (a:User)-[r]->(b:Phone)
RETURN a, collect(b)
```

Now, we convert that to fluent Cypher:

```
var results = client.Cypher
    .Match("(a:User)-[r]->(b:Phone)")
    .Return((a, b) => new {
        User = a.As<User>(),
        Phones = b.CollectAs<Phone>()
    })
    .Results;
```

You can then use this rather easily:

```
foreach (var result in results)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} has {1} phone numbers", result.User.Name, result.Phones.Count());
```

You will need classes like these, that match your node property model:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}

public class Phone
{
    public string number { get; set; }
    public string type_of_number { get; set; }
}
```

Again, **please** go and read https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher and https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher-examples.

Answer (score -1):

Add a .ToList() at the end of your command?
Like this :

```
var myList = ((IRawGraphClient) client).ExecuteGetCypherResults<**i_need_Collection**>(
                    new CypherQuery("match (a:User)-[r]->(b:Phone) return a,collect(b)", null, CypherResultMode.Set))
                .Select(un => un.Data).ToList();
```

Comment: firstly i need ExecuteGetCypherResults<CLASS TO DEFINE DATA>.